# Codeigniter URL Overlapping. Not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my code below.

```
<li><a href="about/why">Why share?</a></li><li>
```

But after I apply this i manage to redirect to the page but when i try to press another page the url will be keep adding like this and cause page not found.

[The page look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXdTP.png)
[But when i try to link to home page, the url won't change back to /home only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSZlt.png)
Any solution? or another way to link the page? 
Need help on this!
Thanks!

Comment: Kindly explain your question properly.... With examples or live screenshots or anything...

Comment: Did u defined routes???

Comment: for my routes, anything else i need to define?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your `base_url()` in `config.php`, and call the `url_helper` so that you can then use it.

**Step by Step Instructions:**

1. in `application/config/config.php`, set your `base_url`, I prefer to use something like this:

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/';
   ```
2. in `application/config/autoload.php`, add url helper:

   ```
   $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
   ```
3. Use it in your views like this:

   ```
   <a href="<?= base_url('about/why') ?>" > link </a>
   ```

Read this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 2):

Your href should have a slash in front of it so that it goes to "root".

```
<li><a href="/about/why">Why share?</a></li><li>
```

If not, the browser will think it is **relative** to the current route. Or use Codeigniter's built-in site_url() function

```
<li><a href="<?=site_url("about/why")?>">Why share?</a></li>
```

Read about relative/absolute here: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: I think your /application/config/config.php base_url is set wrongly. Or it could be your HMVC plugin is messing with the base_url.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter_hmvc/';
that's my base url for config.